# display mysql newline in HTML

Tags: mysql, html, newline, line-breaks

Certain fields in our mysql db appear to contain newline characters so that if I SELECT on them something like the following will be returned for a single SQL call:

```
Life to be sure is nothing much to lose

But young men think it is and we were young
```

If I want to preserve the line breaks when displaying this field on a webpage, is the standard solution to write a script to replace '\n\r' with a br HTML tag or is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming PHP here...

`nl2br()` adds in `<br />` for every `\n`.  Don't forget to escape the content first, to prevent XSS attacks.  See below:

```
<?php echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($content)); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, is there a way to add 2 <br> tags?

Answer (score 4):

HTML is a **markup** language. Regardless of how many linebreaks you put in the source code, you won't see anything from it back in the presentation (of course assuming you aren't using `<pre>` or `white-space:pre`). HTML uses the `<br>` element to represent a linebreak. So you basically indeed need to convert the real and invisible linebreaks denoted by the characters [`xA`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000a/index.htm) (newline, linefeed, LF, `\n`) and/or [`xD`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000d/index.htm) (carriage return, CR, `\r`) by a HTML `<br>` element.

In most programming languages you can just do this by a **string replace** of `"\n"` by `"<br>"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it in `<pre>` .. `</pre>`.

Comment: <pre> has a semantic that goes well beyond newlines, and I think does not apply well to the case.

Comment: Yes. In the end it all depends on the task.