# Json result to html (Newline)

Tags: html, json

If I set the following string into a div how can I get the newline working at HTML?

```
{
"s":"Phrase1.\n\nPhrase2"
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: @user285677 Few people will want to help you if you don't accept valid answers to your questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [display mysql newline in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882754/display-mysql-newline-in-html)

Comment: You can see an example of using `.replace()` method here http://www.lampcoder.com/how-to-parse-line-breaks-using-jquery-post-method-and-json/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foo.innerHTML = myObj.s.replace(/\n/g,"<br>");
```

Comment: changed to foo.innerHTML = myObj.s.replace(/\n/g,"<br />");

Comment: you might need to escape the \ charater /\\n/g

Comment: @benbyford No, you don't.

Comment: @benbyford The OP's code shows a single ASCII newline character. In a literal regex, that is represented as `\n`. If you wrote `/\\n/` it would match two ASCII characters, a backslash followed by a letter n.

Comment: sorry was getting confused as \ is used to escape characters but maybe not in this context then it would appear

Answer (score 7):

Wrap preformatted text in <pre> tags:

```
<pre>{ "s":"Phrase1.\n\nPhrase2" }</pre>
```

Shows up as:

```
{ "s":"Phrase1.

Phrase2" }
```

**Edit:** Another option would be to set the div's style or class to behave the same as a pre tag:

```
<div style="whitespace:pre"/>
```

Comment: Given that the subject and tag includes "JSON" I assume the OP is accessing an `s` property of a JSON return value and setting text to that value.

Comment: Well, it is a json-formatted string.  It may have nothing to do with Javascript JSON object.  Even if it does, you could still wrap the contents in a <pre> tag.

Comment: I think you mean the CSS property `white-space` not `whitespace`.

Answer (score 2):

```
{"s", "phrase1.<br /><br />"phrase2"}
```